# Using IF/ELSE for conditioning WHERE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, where-clause

I'm trying to run this sp but... I cannot figure out where is the mistake. can you help me?

```
alter procedure prova @condizione=1, @parametro=39
    @condizione1 int,
    @parametro int
as

begin
declare @condizione int
set @condizione = @condizione1


    SET NOCOUNT ON
select  pf.CostumerCode, pf.BelongTo
from    tbprodfin pf
    where 
    CASE @condizione
        WHEN 1 THEN pf.IdPF
        WHEN 2 THEN pf.BelongTo
    END  = @parametro

end
```

Comment: Explain what you are trying to achieve. Your Query looks fine

Comment: Are you getting error like Incorrect syntax near **alter procedure prova**

Answer (score 0):

Given the little information provided: i suppose to change your select clause to sth. like

```
select  pf.CostumerCode, pf.BelongTo
from    tbprodfin pf
where 1 = 1
    and (   (@condizione = 1 and @parametro = pf.IdPF)
        or  (@condizione = 2 and @parametro = pf.BelongTo))
```

This might not work initially but it should get you startet as i hope. Also, see this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629132/conditional-where-clause-in-sql-server).

Answer (score 0):

try it like that

```
  CREATE procedure prova @condizione int =1,
 @parametro int =39,
    @condizione1 int    --what for??
as
begin
SET NOCOUNT ON
if @condizione=1
begin
select  pf.CostumerCode, pf.BelongTo
from    tbprodfin pf
where pf.IdPF= @parametro
end 
else 
begin
if @condizione=2
begin
select  pf.CostumerCode, pf.BelongTo
from    tbprodfin pf
where pf.BelongTo= @parametro
end  
end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand what are u want. There is result with use CASE ...

```
select  pf.CostumerCode, pf.BelongTo
from    tbprodfin pf
    where 
    (CASE WHEN @condizione = 1 THEN pf.IdPF
          WHEN @condizione = 2 THEN pf.BelongTo END) = @parametro
```

Comment: I think the CASA solution is the one which I would use, otherwise I had to repeat so many IF how much condition I have.