# How to create a parameter for multiple columns in SSRS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, reporting-services

I have created a report, the columns are like this below:

```
Date        
Sponsorsource    
totaldeal   
totalnewcardeal    
totalusedcardeal
```

Now, I want to create a parameter "dealtype". 
The Parameter dealtype has 3 labels:

```
totaldeal, 
totalnewcardeal, 
totalusedcardeal
```

If I select "totaldeal" in parameter "dealtype, the report will show like this:

```
Date        
Sponsorsource    
totaldeal
```

However, when I created parameter "dealtype", I added 3 lables and values of totaldeal, totalusedcarsdeal, totalnewcarsdeal in section of "specify value''

When I preview the report, I select "totaldeal" in parameter "dealtype", The column and values of totalusedcarsdeal and totalnewcarsdeal still showed up, like this:

```
Parameter dealtype= totaldeal
Report:
Date        
Sponsorsource    
totaldeal   
totalnewcardeal    
totalusedcardeal
```

Can anyone help me one it? Thank you very much!!

Comment: This is long process but here s hint - 1) Show hide column based on the selection set the expression for visibility. 2) If parameters are passed depending on the selection use the [Conditional where clause.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629132/conditional-where-clause-in-sql-server/18629782#18629782)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't restricted the columns you return. 
You could try this:

```
SELECT DATE
    ,Sponsorsource
    ,CASE @dealtype
        WHEN 'Total Deal'
            THEN totaldeal
        WHEN 'Total New Car Deal'
            THEN totalnewcardeal
        WHEN 'Total Used Car Deal'
            THEN totalusedcardeal
        ELSE NULL
        END AS 'Deal Type'
FROM Deals
```

Answer (score 0):

For any column that you want to show or hide based on your parameter, you would right click on the column (the grey rectangle above the column) and select **Column Visibility**. Click on **Show or Hide Based on Expression**. In the totaldeal column expression, enter

> =IIF(Parameters!dealtype.Value = "totaldeal", False, True)

And do the same for the other columns - changing the **"totaldeal"** to the column name that you put in your parameter selection list (**totaldeal, totalnewcardeal, totalusedcardeal**).