# How to write this Conditional where clause in SQl Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Hi I have the following type of query:

```
Select a,b from tab1 whre tab1.id in 
 (Select id from tab2 where x=1 and y=2 and  z>getdate())
```

Now z is a datetime column in tab2 and it is nullable column.So I want the check  z > getdate() only if it is not null.
Checked [Conditional WHERE clause in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629132/conditional-where-clause-in-sql-server) but could not do it accurately.Basically I dont want the 'z' column check in the above query if it is null in tab2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean:

```
Select a,b from tab1 where tab1.id in 
 (Select id from tab2 where x=1 and y=2 and  (z is null or (z is not null and z>getdate())))
```

Comment: Actually, I don't think the `z is not null` check is necessary, but it helps me see things clearly

Answer (score 1):

I think you need a combination of [AND](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188372.aspx) and [OR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms188361.aspx) operators.  When combining these you need to be aware of [operator precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190276.aspx).  In my example I've used brackets to ensure that x, y AND z are checked together, with z then rechecked separately.  The query returns any record where check block 1 OR 2 is true.

In my example I've used a [JOIN](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191472(v=sql.105).aspx) but you can apply this same technique to your original sub query.

Example

```
SELECT
    t1.a,
    t1.b
FROM
    Tab1 AS t1
        INNER JOIN Tab2 AS t2            ON t1.Id = t2.Id
WHERE
    (
        -- Check block 1.
        t2.x = 1
        AND t2.y = 1
        AND t2.z > GETDATE()                
    )
    -- Check block 2.
    OR z IS NULL
;
```

**EDIT:** I'm not entirely sure I understand the question.  If you could provide some sample records and the expected output that would help.