# TSQL Equal or Not Equal conditional in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Based on a declared variable, is it possible to switch between not equal and equal in the where clause?

For example, if the variable @InState is set to true, then return all the addresses with a state equal to 'CA', if false, return all of the addresses with states <> 'CA'.

Code:

```
DECLARE @InState bit
SET @InState = 1

SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tAddresses ADDR
WHERE ADDR.Status = 'A'
AND ADDR.State =
  CASE WHEN @InState = 1
  THEN
    'CA'
  ELSE
    ''
```

The ELSE in the code above, returns every state including 'CA'. I need to return every other state, not equal to 'CA'.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional where clause in Sql Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629132/conditional-where-clause-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd try to avoid `CASE` statements in the `WHERE` clause and go for something like this;

Test Data;

```
DECLARE @Instate bit; SET @Instate = 1

CREATE TABLE #Addresses (ID int, State varchar(2), Status varchar(2))
INSERT INTO #Addresses (ID, State, Status)
VALUES
(1,'CA','A')
,(2,'NY','A')
,(3,'CA','A')
,(4,'NJ','A')
,(5,'FL','A')
,(6,'CA','A')
,(7,'ND','A')
```

Query

```
DECLARE @InState bit
SET @InState = 1

SELECT * 
FROM #Addresses ADDR
WHERE ADDR.Status = 'A'
AND 
(
    (@InState = 1
    AND ADDR.State = 'CA')
    OR
    (@InState <> 1
    AND ADDR.State <> 'CA')
)
```

When `@Instate = 1` then these are the results;

```
ID  State   Status
1   CA      A
3   CA      A
6   CA      A
```

When `@Instate = 0` then you get this;

```
ID  State   Status
2   NY      A
4   NJ      A
5   FL      A
7   ND      A
```

Calculations in a `WHERE` clause is going to kill your performance by making your query non `SARGable`;

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable

Comment: Thanks Rich, this worked for me. I did have to modify it slightly though to get it to display the out of state addresses. Changed the line `@InState <> 1` to `(@InState <> 1 AND ADDR.State <> 'CA')`

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that, i think you'll need to change that to a <> rather than = take a look at my updated answer.

Comment: Yeah, thanks. That was a typo in my comment. Fixed it.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry for the delay, had to wait on the stack overflow timer to mark a question as accepted.

Comment: No worries at all, as long as your problem is sorted then I'm happy. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

This is the ugly one, but it works for me,

....

```
AND ADDR.State =
CASE WHEN @InState = 1 THEN 'CA' ElSE ADDR.State END
AND ADDR.State <>
CASE WHEN @InState = 0 THEN 'CA' ElSE ADDR.State END
```

Comment: I think this would suppress all results, don't you want to wrap those last two in brackets and use an OR between them?

Comment: You are right. I used '=' to test both cases. However, it does have issues when it's NOT equal. This should be OK ... CASE WHEN @InState = 0 THEN 'CA' ElSE 'something non-exist' END

Answer (score 1):

Not a where clause but I think it is sargable

```
SELECT ADDR.* 
FROM dbo.tAddresses ADDR
left join dbo.tAddresses ADDRin 
      on ADDRin.id = ADDR.id  
     and ADDRin.State = 'CA' 
     and @InState = 1
left join dbo.tAddresses ADDRout 
      on ADDRout.id = ADDR.id 
     and ADDRout.State <> 'CA' 
     and @InState = 0
WHERE ADDR.Status = 'A'
  AND (ADDRin.id is not null or ADDRout.id is not null)


SELECT ADDR.* 
  FROM dbo.tAddresses ADDR
 where ADDR.Status = 'A' 
   and ADDR.State  = 'CA' 
   and @InState = 1
UNION ALL
SELECT ADDR.* 
  FROM dbo.tAddresses ADDR
 where ADDR.Status = 'A'
   and ADDR.State <> 'CA' 
   and @InState <> 1
```

Comment: That'll just return everything in ADDR though surely? By doing both of those inner joins you're not actually excluding anything.

Comment: @RichBenner Surely?  Why don't you test it out.

Comment: I've just tested it and it suppresses all results, regardless of whether @instate is set to 1 or 0

Comment: @RichBenner So first you assert it will return everything and then you test and returns nothing.   And you down vote.    Not compelled to educate you.

Comment: Just a note, I haven't downvoted. Just trying to make sure that the OP gets the correct answer. I've put a picture on my answer to prove I haven't downvoted.

Comment: If your answer had left joins and this code at the end it would work perfectly 'AND (ADDRin.ID IS NOT NULL OR ADDRout.ID IS NOT NULL)'

Answer (score 1):

How about using IF ELSE

```
IF (@Instate=1)
BEGIN 
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tAddresses ADDR
WHERE ADDR.Status = 'A'
AND ADDR.State ='CA'
END
ELSE 
BEGIN
SELECT * 
FROM dbo.tAddresses ADDR
WHERE ADDR.Status = 'A'
AND ADDR.State <>'CA'
END
```

I know its procedural not sure about the  performance aspect. But another option.

Comment: Thank Biju for sharing that solution. I'm still learning more about SQL, so it's always good to see more than one way to solve the same problem.