# Condition within Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to add  'if else' condition within a where clause, but not sure how would I do it. Looking at the below table set, I am trying to filter the results where the query would extract all the Product line subtypes and add a condition only when the  **[Product Line Subtype] = 'Marine'**. When it is Marine,  then it should consider only two combinations of **Section** and **Profit Code** while omitting other combinations.

**Combination 1** When Prod line Subtype = Marine then Section = Inland and Profit Code = Builders

**Combination 2** When Prod line Subtype = Marine then Section = Ocean and Profit Code = Stocks

My actual table has larger sets of distinct combinations than showed in the below table when Prod line Subtype = Marine, but I just want to filter only the above two combinations to my results set. Any help would be much appreciated!

**Main table**

```
+--+------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|  |Prod line Subtype | Section     |  Profit Code    |
+--+------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|  | Marine           | Inland      |  Builders       |
|  | Marine           | Ocean       |  Stock          | 
|  | Property         | General     |  Transport      |  
|  | Energy           | Source      |  Others         |  
|  | Property         | General     |  Transport      |   
|  | Energy           | Source      |  Transport      |  
|  | Marine           | Inland      |  Transport      |    
|  | Marine           | Floaters    |  Transport      |    
|  | Marine           | Cargo       |  Others         |    
+--+------------------+-------------+---------------- +
```

**Expected Results**

```
+--+------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|  |Prod line Subtype | Section     |  Profit Code    |
+--+------------------+-------------+-----------------+
|  | Marine           | Inland      |  Builders       |
|  | Marine           | Ocean       |  Stock          | 
|  | Property         | General     |  Transport      |  
|  | Energy           | Source      |  Others         |  
|  | Property         | General     |  Transport      |   
|  | Energy           | Source      |  Transport      |  
+--+------------------+-------------+---------------- +
```

My query attempt:

```
select *
from #Step1 
where c1.row_ord = 1
and c1.[Prod Line Subtype]  = 'Marine' AND (
    (c1.[Section] = 'Inland' AND c1.[Profit Code] = 'Builder')
    OR (c1.[Section] = 'Ocean' AND c1.[Profit Code] = 'Stock')
)
```

Comment: You can use a case statement for this, what's your current query?

Comment: It's generally better to use `AND`/`OR`  instead of `case` _expressions_ in `WHERE` clauses.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional WHERE clause in SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629132/conditional-where-clause-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
    Select * from [Your table]
    Where ([Prod line Subtype]<>'Marine' Or 
       (Section='Inland' And [Profit Code]='Builders') Or
       (Section='Ocean' And [Profit Code]='Stocks')    
    )
```

Can omit the [Prod line Subtype]='Marine' from or conditions