# Isnull - Case and conditions on where clause

Tags: sql-server

I have a code snippet where I have a bunch of 'where' conditions merged with 'and' clause. I want to do the below operation:

```
...     
     and admission_date > release_date
     and case when @sample = 'typeA'
            then 
            (
            (isnull(@toll_id, 0) > 0 and exists(select fk_id from dbo.tollitem where toll_id = @toll_id and isdel=0))
            or 
            (isnull(@toll_id, 0) = 0)
            )
```

So I have a parameter as @Sample which has two values - Type A or Type B. I want to check the condition on where clause only when @sample = typeA. 
Above is my code and I am getting incorrect syntax error. Any help?

Comment: Post the error message you're getting.
And you're missing the END statement for the CASE.

Comment: Missing `end` keyword ?

Comment: oops sorry. I got incorrect syntax error near '>' Else part is just select '1'. I don't have specific code for else part

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Conditional WHERE clause in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18629132/conditional-where-clause-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should definitely rewrite this as :

```
and admission_date > release_date
     and  
       (@sample = 'typeA' and
            (((isnull(@toll_id, 0) > 0 and exists(select fk_id from dbo.tollitem where toll_id = @toll_id and isdel=0))
            or 
            (isnull(@toll_id, 0) = 0)
            )))
```

Comment: This code helped me. But there is one more parenthesis needed at the end if I'm not wrong.

Comment: @Jiah define "more than needed". Sometimes they are places for clarity but aren't needed--yet doesn't hurt anything.

Answer (score 2):

That's not how a `CASE` expression works. In the `WHERE` clause you still need to make a boolean expression. Thus:

```
WHERE CASE WHEN Col1 = 1 THEN Col2 = 2 OR Col3 = 3 ELSE Col4 = 1 END;
```

Is completely wrong, the `CASE` only completes one side of the expression, and is also trying to evaluate Boolean expressions inside the `WHEN`. A `WHEN` returns a value, not a boolean. A correct use of `CASE` would be (unrelated to above example):

```
WHERE CASE TransactionType WHEN 'Transfered' THEN 'New Business'
                           WHEN 'Adjustment' THEN 'Endorsement'
                           ELSE TransactionType END = @Trantype;
```

This is a bit of a shot in the dark, but I think what you're after is:

```
AND admission_date > release_date
AND (@sample = 'typeA'
AND  ((isnull(@toll_id, 0) > 0 AND EXISTS(SELECT fk_id
                                          FROM dbo.tollitem
                                          WHERE toll_id = @toll_id
                                            AND isdel=0))
 OR  (isnull(@toll_id, 0) = 0)))
```

Comment: Larnu can you edit the code to show @sample = typeB ?

Comment: @Jiah I'm pretty sure you can figure how to do that one yourself. The **volunteers** on SO aren't here to support the code they provide you (and changing the value of a literal string is extremely simple). It's your job to make sure you understand it and can support it yourself. if you don't understand the code your provided, you can ask about it, but if you still don't, then I more strongly suggest you don't use it.

Comment: totally agree!! I understood the solution given and edited my code to fit my requirement but forgot to update here :) Thanks for the support